# Transforming a Connectable Flux into Hot via share operator not working

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have below program which first creates an interval flux, taking 5 elements and subscribe to it. 
Post that,I convert it to connectable flux using **replay** operator with **auto connect** 2 and then convert it to hot publisher. However,any subequent subsription doesn't receive any data irrespective of any number of subscriber I add. (sleep is used here to show effect of hot stream)

```
        Flux<Long> flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(5);
        flux.subscribe();
        flux = flux.replay().autoConnect(2).share();   //hot publisher     
        flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("first " + aLong));   //no data
        sleep(2000);
        flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("second " + aLong));  //no data
```

The catching thing is that, if I set auto connect to 1 (effectively making it a normal flux), then expected behaviour is observed (Output shown below).

Output: 
first 0 
first 1 
first 2 
second 2 
first 3 
second 3 
first 4 
second 4

Please clarify or correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Flux<Long> flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(2);
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("source " + aLong));
    flux = flux.replay().autoConnect(2).share();   //hot publisher
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("first " + aLong));   
    sleep(2000);
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("second " + aLong));
```

output :
source 0
source 1
(here only source printed because, we are calling share() after subscribe)

```
 Flux<Long> flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(2);
    flux.replay().autoConnect(3).share().
        subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("source " + aLong));   
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("first " + aLong));
    sleep(2000);
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("second " + aLong));
```

output :
first 0
first 1
second 0
second 1
(here source not printed )

```
Flux<Long> flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(2).replay().autoConnect(3);
    flux.share().subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("source " + aLong));  
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("first " + aLong));
    sleep(2000);
    flux.subscribe(aLong -> System.out.println("second " + aLong));
```

output :
source 0
first 0
second 0
source 1
first 1
second 1

Observe these 3 scenarios and its outputs,its important here where and when you are subscribed and shared